# If he had time, he always called in to see us

Tags: conditional-constructions

**If he had time, he always called in to see us.**

The structure of this sentence is making me puzzled. I mean why it could not have been like this- *"If he had time, he would have called in to see us."*

It is true that it might be the past habit of the person of always calling in whenever he got time, *but, does it make sense in conditional sentences like this? If yes, then could you make me understand how?*

Comment: It might help if you understand ***If*** there as effectively equivalent to ***When[ever]***.

Comment: But is it even the convention? or should i take that IF as WHEN only because it makes more sense?

Comment: To be honest, I'm having trouble understanding what *possible* different meanings could apply with your exact context. We know that *he always called in to see us* isn't 100% true - it's subject to the precondition of him having time to do so. But for me as a competent native speaker, it makes no difference at all whether that restriction is expressed using ***If*** or ***When***. There's obviously a difference in other contexts though - *I'll do it **if** I have time* (but maybe never) is a much weaker commitment than *I'll do it **when** I have time* (eventually, for sure).

Comment: Note that your alternative *If he had time, he **would have called** in to see us* would normally mean something completely different. The implication there is that he ***never*** called (***because*** he never had time).

Comment: Do native speakers really speak sentences like this?

Comment: I understand your problem. More accurately, I understand ***that you have a problem***, even though I don't *really* see why. Presumably that's because I'm so used to encountering both ***If*** and ***When[ever]*** in such contexts with exactly the same meaning that it's hard for me to conceptualize how you can see two distinct/conflicting meanings. That's why I'm *commenting* here - to get a better handle on how ***you're*** interpreting the alternatives.

Comment: Now, I think, since the second clause does not resemble with standard conditional sentence, it is more appropriate to interpret it the way you said. Moreover, my alternative sentence entirely different and bears fully different meaning viz-a-vie the real context of the sentence.

Comment: [Here's the evidence](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=If+I+have+time+I%2CWhen+I+have+time+I&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIf%20I%20have%20time%20I%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWhen%20I%20have%20time%20I%3B%2Cc0) that both forms are about equally common. You can drill down to read the specific usages in context, but I'd be surprised if that led you to think they carried different ***meanings***.

Comment: Another possibility is "If he had time, he would always call in to see us", meaning that he was in the habit of doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrite:

> If he had time, he would have called in to see us.

This implies a hypothetical, that he "would have" called in, which suggests that he in fact didn't call in, and also suggests that this was because he didn't have time.

It would more correctly be written as:

> If he'd had time, he would have called in to see us.

"He'd" meaning "he had".

> If he had time, he always called in to see us.

This states that he "always called in", meaning that he in fact did call in, and also tells us that this was only the case when he had time (if he didn't have time, he didn't call in, but if he did have time, he [always] called in).

Answer (score -1):

You're correct, the sentence is awkward because of mixing conditional and non-conditional modes.   It's not "wrong" however.  We'd probably not think it sounded strange and understand it to mean:

```
When he had time, he always called in to see us.
```

which is the natural way of saying "in the past, whenever he had the time to do so, he did actually call in to see us."  This refers to multiple occasions, and the subject did actually "call in" - more than once. We could instead say:

```
If he had time, he would have called in to see us.
```

which means in some unspecified time frame in the past, he ***did not*** "call in" but would have if he had the time to do so.

If there was just a single instance that he "called in", you could say either of:

```
When he had the time, he called in to see us.
He had the time to call in once.
```

The first one could mean he "called in" a single time, or many times.  The second one explicitly states that it was just one time.

Comment: I don't agree *the sentence is awkward*. It's normal everyday English.

Comment: I said it wasn't strange or odd-sounding conversationally.   But it is awkward or casual grammar.   An English teacher might deduct a mark, style guides might recommend against it, and you'd want to use a different construction in formal communication.  Avoid mixed modes if possible.

Answer (score -2):

This sentence could be rewritten differently, to understand its meaning. This particular case could also be understood as "Each moment he had time, he always called in to see us.", or something else that would suits you more.

Now, regarding conditional sentence, the only way to make it work is to add "would" before the verb, like you did above. There aren't supposed to be other manners to express a condition, than the addition of a "would" before the verb("might" being an exception). Many cases in English work this way, such as expressing regrets.

"If only he had time, he would always call in to see us", is one example among others.

Comment: Your final example doesn't strike me as something native speakers would say. ***If only*** strongly implies a hypothetical situation that ***never*** happened, but ***always*** strongly implies it ***did*** (*often*, in fact).